# How to clone jQuery-altered html

Tags: jquery, quicksand

I am trying to use the original quicksand code from [here](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html)

```
 $(function() {

 // bind radiobuttons in the form
 var $filterType = $('#filter input[name="type"]');
 var $filterSort = $('#filter input[name="sort"]');

 // get the first collection
 var $applications = $('#applications');

 // clone applications to get a second collection
 var $data = $applications.clone();
```

Everything works fine, except from the fact that the elements in $('#applications') have been slightly altered using jQuery (e.g. some div elements have been hidden and some classes have been swapped). Using clone() I can only manage to clone the original source code.

Is there a way to clone the 'live' version of $('#applications')?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you really, but I see that you talking about div contains html code changed, and that change not applied to `$data` that is a clone of `$applications` , I think you can try this code and see if this do what you want:

After `var $data = $applications.clone();`

Add these lines:

```
$('#applications').change(function() {
    $applications = $('#applications');
    $data = $applications.clone();
});
```

I hope that's work if my understand is correct.

**Edit:** Ops I forgot to say, add the following code when you alter div :

```
$("#applications").change();
```

this code will fire change event, so refresh cloned object.